# Can one use PF_PACKET sockets on Linux to send raw packets without filling Ethernet data?

Tags: linux, tcp

Looking at `tcpreplay`'s [source](http://tcpreplay.sourcearchive.com/documentation/3.3.1-1/sendpacket_8c-source.html), found the idea of using PF_PACKET instead of AF_INET+SOCK_RAW.

However, can't tell from existing documentation if it's possible for PF_PACKET to send raw IP packet without filling Ethernet part of packet.

It's a question of performance - a long-living application will get lost with large ARP cache lookup and/or requests, so the profit of expected performance gain will get lost; yet I want to send raw packets faster than allowed by SOCK_RAW family - which is a huge troublemaker with its TCP_NODELAY handling.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to skip the ARP cache in linux, you SHOULD fill the Ethernet header.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you can't do `PF_PACKET` without filling in the ethernet header.